# glDatePicker date format

Tags: javascript

I'm sorry,

I ask how to format the date in gldatapicker 2 ?

by:

```
    $(window).load(function()
    {


{
    showAlways: true,
    allowMonthSelect: false,
    allowYearSelect: false,
    selectableYears: [2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020],


selectableDateRange: [ { from: new Date(2013, 2, 01), to: new Date(2013, 2, 10) } ]
```

to:

selectableDateRange: [ { from: new Date(01, 2, 2013), to: new Date(10, 2, 2013) } ]

and if you can change from December = 0

in December = 1

Thank you and sorry for the trouble but I can not find any answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We can use 'onClick' callback to format the date.

```
$('.date-picker').glDatePicker(
    {
        onClick: function(target, cell, date, data) {
            target.val(date.getFullYear() + '-' +
                date.getMonth() + '-' +
                date.getDate());

            if(data != null) {
                alert(data.message + '\n' + date);
            }
        }            
    }
);
```

Comment: Another option is to use the `onChange` function

Answer (score 1):

function GetFormattedDate(todayTime) {

```
//alert((todayTime.getMonth() + 1) + '#' + todayTime.getDate() + '#' +  todayTime.getFullYear());

return  todayTime.getFullYear()+'-'+(todayTime.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + todayTime.getDate() ;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Create a small function to convert the already formatted date.
Parse the formatted date to the function
Assign el a value from that.

The function I created in this case is toDate

```
`
onClick: (function(el, cell, date, data) {
        var armco= date.toLocaleDateString();       
        armco=toDate(armco);
        el.val(armco);
    })

function toDate(selector) {

    var from = selector.split("/");

    var myformat=from[2]+'-'+from[1]+'-'+from[0];   

    return myformat;
}
`
```